# Spin polarization without magnetization

Tags: quantum-spin, polarization, magnetic-moment

I am wondering whether it is possible to have a system, which is spin-polarized but the system as a whole remains un-magnetized. The magnetic dipole moment and the spin/internal angular momentum are related as,

$$m^{\alpha\beta} = \chi\, s^{\alpha\beta}$$

Since I am working with a system made of spin-1/2 particles, the tensor $s^{\alpha\beta}$ is non-vanishing and thus so is $m^{\alpha\beta}$. Now what I would like to know is, whether it is possible to have a system, that has no net magnetization, $M$ in spite of non-zero $m^{\alpha\beta}$, although the system may have net spin-polarization.

Comment: I don't suppose you are asking about cases where orbital magnetzation cancels out the spin one?

Comment: No. I am more focused on plasma like systems or some fluids.

Comment: Doesn't every diamagnetic material fulfil this condition?

Comment: Can diamagnetic materials be spin polarized? I don't know that. What do you think?

Comment: I find the idea of a displaced magnetic field in diamagnetic materials to be outdated. Rather, I assume that the alignment of paired electrons with opposing spins leads to an equilibrium of the inner magnetic potential and the outer magnetic field. Diamagnets have no macroscopic magnetic field direction.

https://imgur.com/a/SSYkYqB